# How to clear Firefox search box terms after submission?

Tags: firefox

There didn't seem to be anything relevant in about:config.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is clear the text field because you are on a UNIX like OS and want to use middle click to paste, there are some extensions for that. I use [ClearFields](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/clear-fields/).

It adds a button to the right of the search box and clicking on it clears the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear a specific entry from the form/search history by getting it to show up, then using the up/down arrow keys to highlight the entry, then using Shift-Del to delete it.

If you want to clear your history less discriminately, you can use the Clear Recent History option in the Tools menu.